# How to translate ng-bootstrap input date-picker - NgbInputDatepicker i18n?

Tags: angular, datepicker, internationalization, ng-bootstrap

We are using the 'ng-bootstrap' date picker input component.

While the date-picker itself can be translated using `NgbDatepickerI18n` according to the example at this [plnkr](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/datepicker/demos/i18n/plnkr.html), the input date picker uses the `NgbInputDatepicker` directive.

How can this directive be translated using the same services that are used for translating the date-picker?

Comment: The exact same way. http://plnkr.co/edit/wKsmGJe4yIZEwZ31gM0B?p=preview

Comment: Ah this makes me hate Angular even more, is there seriously no less complicated way to translate the controls...

Comment: @Phill It's not really an Angular problem but more a `ng-bootstrap` problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the exact same way. The NgbInputDatepicker, when toggled, displays an NgbDatepicker, which gets its labels from a service.