# Use a ng-bootstrap internationalized datepicker in an input

Tags: angular, datepicker, internationalization, ng-bootstrap

I want to have a french datepicker in an input form.

Here is the ng-bootstrap example to have an "english" one:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
        <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) they explained how to make a french one using `<ngbd-datepicker-i18n></ngbd-datepicker-i18n>` with a custom datepicker and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504283/how-to-translate-ng-bootstrap-input-date-picker-ngbinputdatepicker-i18n) there is some more details on how to use it.

But what I want is to use the same thing that they used above, whith the template reference variable `#d="ngbDatepicker"` inside my `input` tag. Something like `#d="myCustomNgbDatepicker"`.

Is it possible ? And if yes, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make two things

1. a DateI18nFormater extends NgbDatepickerI18n
2. a DateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter

in your module.ts

```
providers: [
        { provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: DateParserFormatter },
        I18n, 
        { provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: DateI18nFormater }
    ]
```

Comment: What is `DateParserFormatter`? Does it come from a module? is it selfmade? I cant find it. The same with `DateI18nFormater`.

Answer (score 3):

Added to what Menna Ramadan says in the ngbDatePicker documentation is the link to a demo that has the same structure:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/datepicker/i18n/stackblitz.html

Here's what your service should be like (in my case for Spanish)

**custom-datepicker-i18n.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDatepickerI18n, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

const I18N_VALUES = {
  'es': {
    weekdays: ['L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S', 'D'],
    months: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
  }
  // other languages you would support
};

// Define a service holding the language. You probably already have one if your app is i18ned. Or you could also
// use the Angular LOCALE_ID value
@Injectable()
export class I18n {
  language = 'es';
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomDatepickerI18nService extends NgbDatepickerI18n {

  constructor(private _i18n: I18n) {
    super();
  }

  getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {
    return I18N_VALUES[this._i18n.language].weekdays[weekday - 1];
  }
  getMonthShortName(month: number): string {
    return I18N_VALUES[this._i18n.language].months[month - 1];
  }
  getMonthFullName(month: number): string {
    return this.getMonthShortName(month);
  }

  getDayAriaLabel(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    return `${date.day}-${date.month}-${date.year}`;
  }
}
```

Then you provide the service in the component that uses the ngbdatepicker

**my-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { NgbDatepickerI18n } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CustomDatepickerI18nService, I18n } from 'src/app/services/ngbpicker/custom-datepicker-i18n.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-mi-perfil',
  templateUrl: './mi-perfil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mi-perfil.component.css'],
  providers: [I18n,{provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: CustomDatepickerI18nService}]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

You should only need that to make it work.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I use the same HTML syntex

```
<div class="q-datepicker position-relative w-100">
            <input
                formControlName="From"
                class=" form-control rounded-corner bg-white primary-font-color"
                placement="bottom"
                placeholder=""
                [minDate]=""
                ngbDatepicker
                #d="ngbDatepicker"
                readonly=""
            />
            <button
                type="button"
                (click)="d.toggle()"
            >
                <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
```

Then I create a new service file including the followings:

```
const I18N_VALUES = {
'Eng': {weekdays: ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'],
months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 
'Nov', 'Dec'],
},
'Frn': {
 weekdays: ['Lu', 'Ma', 'Me', 'Je', 'Ve', 'Sa', 'Di'],
 months: ['Jan', 'Fév', 'Mar', 'Avr', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil', 'Aou', 'Sep','Oct','Nov', 'Déc']
 }  };




 @Injectable()
language: string = 'Eng';
}
```

after That and inside the service create new class which extends `NgbDatepickerI18n` with `super()` inside the constructor

and implement the followings:

```
getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {
return I18N_VALUES[this._i18n.language].weekdays[weekday - 1];}

getMonthShortName(month: number): string {
return I18N_VALUES[this._i18n.language].months[month - 1];}

getMonthFullName(month: number): string {
return this.getMonthShortName(month);}

 getDayAriaLabel(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
return `${date.day}-${date.month}-${date.year}`;}
```

at the end inside your component import the last service and add the following in component

```
providers: [{provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: nameOfYourClassWhichExtendsNgbDatepickerI18n}]
```

Comment: can you please, share the full code of the service including its name?